# How to replace KML data comma to Unicode format?

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode, google-fusion-tables

I tried to importRows to Fusion Table with KML data. But I am getting Error like Method Not Allowed. Because Fusion Table ImportRow options is comma separated values.

below is my original KML data:

```
<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>
-130.24554,56.09688,0.0 -130.01763,55.91078,0.0
</Polygon></outerBoundaryIs></LinearRing></coordinates>
```

after i tried to insert thrown error.

Modified KML data with Unicode Charecter - Replaced comma (,) to `U+002C` after i am tried to insert. Insert has been completed but Map Location not located on the Google Map.

Below is replaced comma (,) to Unicode Charecter:

```
<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>
-130.24554U+002C56.09688U+002C0.0 -130.01763U+002C55.91078U+002C0.0
</Polygon></outerBoundaryIs></LinearRing></coordinates>
```

Answer (score 0):

The comma is the default-delimiter, but it may be changed.

Leave the KML as it is and specify   via the [query-parameter](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/reference/table/importRows#parameters) `delimiter` another delimiter